# jPDFWriter library, writing a table into a pdf file

Tags: java, pdf, datatable

Does anyone know how to use jPDFWriter library(in java) to write a table with rows and columns into a pdf file. I **do not want to use the IText library** commonly used for this because it is not free of charge.

If you can give an example or references to such use it will be helpful. 
I couldn't find anything online.

Answer (score 0):

```
   import com.qoppa.pdfWriter.PDFPrinterJob;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.print.PageFormat;
import java.awt.print.Printable;
import java.util.Vector;

public class PrintPanelToPDF implements Printable
{
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        try
        {
            // create a PDF Printer Job
            PDFPrinterJob printer = (PDFPrinterJob)PDFPrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
            // set the printable object
            printer.setPrintable (new PrintPanelToPDF());
            // set number of copies to 1
            printer.setCopies (1);
            // print and save the document
            printer.print("out.pdf");
            // output done message
            System.out.println("Done!");
        }
        catch (Throwable t)
        {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public JTable createJTable(){

        Vector<String> rowOne = new Vector<String>();
        rowOne.addElement("Row1-Column1");
        rowOne.addElement("Row1-Column2");
        rowOne.addElement("Row1-Column3");

        Vector<String> rowTwo = new Vector<String>();
        rowTwo.addElement("Row2-Column1");
        rowTwo.addElement("Row2-Column2");
        rowTwo.addElement("Row2-Column3");

        Vector<String> columnNames = new Vector<String>();
        columnNames.addElement("Column One");
        columnNames.addElement("Column Two");
        columnNames.addElement("Column Three");

        Vector<Vector> rowData = new Vector<Vector>();
        rowData.addElement(rowOne);
        rowData.addElement(rowTwo);

        JTable table = new JTable(rowData, columnNames);
        table.setVisible(true);
        table.setSize(600, 500);
        //table.setLocation(0,200);
        table.setBounds(30,40,600,600);

        return table;
    }

    public int print (Graphics g, PageFormat pf, int pageIndex)
    {
        if (pageIndex == 0)
        {

            // translate the graphics for margins
            g.translate(0, 0);

            // create a panel with a label and a textfield
            JPanel myPanel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
            myPanel.setName("myPanel");
            myPanel.setBorder(new javax.swing.border.EtchedBorder());
            myPanel.setBounds(new java.awt.Rectangle(0, 0, 612, 792));
            // create a label
            JLabel myLabel = new JLabel("MyLabel");
            myLabel.setText("Label");
            myLabel.setLocation(10, 10);
            myLabel.setSize(50, 20);
            myLabel.setVisible(true);
            // add label to panel
            myPanel.add(myLabel);
            // create a text field
            JTextField myTextField = new JTextField();
            myTextField.setText("My Text");
            myTextField.setLocation(65, 10);
            myTextField.setSize(50, 20);
            myTextField.setVisible(true);
            // add text field to panel
            myPanel.add(myTextField);
            myPanel.add(createJTable());
            // you can add any swing component here
            // .....
            // revalidate and repaint the panel
            myPanel.revalidate();
            myPanel.repaint();
            // print the panel to the graphics on page 0
            myPanel.print (g);
            return Printable.PAGE_EXISTS;
        }
        else
        {
            return Printable.NO_SUCH_PAGE;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This sample is a bit complicated as it makes use of JComponent. So unless you have a user interface and want to print a table displayed in an existing JPanel, you should use the simpler sample program we have in our developer knowledge base which makes use of Graphics2D commands such as drawString and drawRect instead.

https://kbdeveloper.qoppa.com/code-sample-draw-data-table-to-pdf-document/